# How to create a boxplot from t -test

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot, t-test

this is the code and data i already have:

```
library(tidyverse)
t.test(BMIS ~ CONDITION, var.equal =TRUE, data = BMIS_DATA)
descriptive_statistics = BMIS_DATA %>% 
                           group_by(CONDITION) %>% 
                           summarise(
                             mean = mean (BMIS), 
                             sd = sd (BMIS),  
                             n = n ()
                         )
view(descriptive_statistics)
mean_difference = descriptive_statistics [1,2] - descriptive_statistics [2,2]
```

which gave me :

```
Two Sample t-test

data:  BMIS by CONDITION
t = 3.7455, df = 44, p-value = 0.0005201
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  4.299781 14.317362
sample estimates:
mean in group HAPPY   mean in group SAD 
           45.88000            36.57143
```

How do I create some visual data from this?

Comment: library(ggplot2)
ggplot(BMIS_DATA,aes(x=CONDITION,y=BMIS,col=CONDITION))+geom_boxplot()            i added this to create a graph but i now need to make it APA style, i found a code online: theme_apa(
+     legend.pos = "right",
+     legend.use.title = FALSE,
+     legend.font.size = 12,
+     x.font.size = 12,
+     y.font.size = 12,
+     facet.title.size = 12,
+     remove.y.gridlines = TRUE,
+     remove.x.gridlines = TRUE
+ )  but it kept on coming up with error apa theme not found , does anyone know how i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can easily represent the distributions according to your *CONDITION* variable.
The following code allows you to visualize this from boxplots:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(BMIS_DATA,aes(x=CONDITION,y=BMIS,col=CONDITION))+geom_boxplot()
```

Then, the classical functions of the ggplot2 package can be applied. To customize : `?geom_boxplot`.

Comment: library(ggplot2) ggplot(BMIS_DATA,aes(x=CONDITION,y=BMIS,col=CONDITION))+geom_boxplot() i added this to create a graph but i now need to make it APA style, i found a code online: theme_apa( + legend.pos = "right", + legend.use.title = FALSE, + legend.font.size = 12, + x.font.size = 12, + y.font.size = 12, + facet.title.size = 12, + remove.y.gridlines = TRUE, + remove.x.gridlines = TRUE + ) but it kept on coming up with error apa theme not found , does anyone know how i fix this ?

Comment: The apa theme comes from the **jtools** package. Install the jtools package then load it.